# Can't understand homework assignment

Tags: number-theory

Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$ be an odd prime. Prove that if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $−1$ is not a square modulo $p$.

$\textbf{Hint}$ : recall that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a ﬁeld, so that its multiplicative group is a cyclic group
of order $p − 1$. Prove that in any such group the order of $−1$ is $(p − 1)/2$, that the
order of any square is even and deduce that the equation $x
^2 = −1$ cannot be solved
if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

I can't understand the Hint. What does it mean "in any such group"? I mean, what is $-1$ in a generic cyclic group of order $p-1$? Suppose the group is the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Why the order is claimed to be $(p-1)/2$?? Isn't the order of $-1$ always equal to $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, this seems to be a different usage of "order" than is standard. You should look at a fixed generator $\omega$ of the group; that is, $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} = \{\omega^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and call the order of $x$ the minimal $n$ such that $\omega^n = x$ - then the hint will work.

Comment: In fact, the common definition of "order" is always $p-1$ divided by the hint's definition of "order" and vice versa.

Comment: @Cocopuffs i can't still understand this..suppose $x^2=-1(mod p)$ then, if $p$ is congruent to $3$ mod $4$, then $(p-1)/2$ is odd, but $x^2$ is a square, so its order is even, and this is inconsistent with the "order" of $-1$, isn't this the sense of the hint?

Comment: @bateman Yes, this is the contradiction that makes the proof

Comment: @Cocopuffs ok, but this contradiction rests on the fact that $-1$ has order $(p-1)/2$, which is what i can't actually understand

Comment: @bateman $\omega^{p-1} = 1$ is the smallest power of $\omega$ that is one - this follows from the definition. But if $\omega^n = -1$, then $\omega^{2n} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

That hint seems to be using a very different definition of "order" than many of use would use, since clearly $\;(-1)^2=1\,$ in *any* field, but as suggested it maybe the power to which a primitive element$\,w\,$ must be raised to get $\,-1\,$ , which is then clearly $\,\displaystyle{\frac{p-1}2}\,$ . Now

$$x^2=-1=w^{\frac{p-1}2}\implies x^4=w^{p-1}=1$$

from where we'd get $\,4\mid p-1\,$ , which is absurd since $\,p=3k+4\implies p-1=3k+2\,$ , and this isn't divisible by four...